# The curous incident of the missing ppa.ko in debian 3.11 kernel?

Tags: debian, kernel-modules

Ok. Running a version of LDME with a kernel of 3.11-2-amd64 ( basically debian testing).

Suddenly with the installation of this particular kernel the module ppa.ko is gone. Further an `apt-file search` shows that this module does not exist.

Anyone know what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was disabled in the 3.11 build of the debian package. From the package's [changelog](http://ftp-master.metadata.debian.org/changelogs//main/l/linux/linux_3.11.8-1_changelog):

> - Disable parport drivers that are no longer likely to be useful:
>
>   - block: Disable PARIDE
>   - media: Disable VIDEO_BWQCAM, VIDEO_CQCAM, VIDEO_W9966
>   - SCSI: Disable SCSI_IMM, SCSI_PPA

This means the the maintainer no longer felt that Iomega Zip drive support was still useful for Debian users. If you feel this is incorrect, you can file a wishlist bug against the package in the [Debian Bug Tracking System](http://www.debian.org/Bugs/).